# detect pageshow(n) for multiple pages

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-mobile

i have created a handler to trap pageshow for multiple ages like so

```
$(document).on('pageshow',"#novels, #book, #toys",function(event){

}
```

each page has an id like so

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="pagename"></div>
```

how do i get the pages that call the pageshow events, i tried

```
console.log($(this).attr('id'));
```

in the pageshow evens, but got `undefined` in the console

Comment: Have you tried with `$(event.target).attr('id')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### jQuery Mobile <= 1.3

```
$(document).on("pageshow", function () {
  var activePage = $.mobile.activePage[0].id;
  console.log( activePage ); // pageID of active page
});
```

#### jQuery Mobile >= 1.4

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {
  var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage")[0].id;
  console.log( activePage ); // pageID of active page
});
```